# What data is stored inside my POST form a SELECT input

Tags: php, mysql, forms

## Problem

I have a Form with a  dropdown and I need the POSTDATA from it to put into a mysql query but I'm unable to convert to datetime.

### Things I tried

1st Thing I tried:
The values in the  are all datetime from a server table. The user then selects a time and that time is then saved inside a variable using POST.
I then try to convert the value inside the variable back into a time that is usable inside the query.
But this gives the following error:
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in reserveren.php on line 57

2nd Thing I tried:
Directly using the POST inside the query but this gives the following error:
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in reserveren.php on line 57

3rd Thing I tried:
still converting the value but with a different method and that gives this error:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in reserveren.php on line 60

#### Code used

The code for the 1st try looks like this:

```
$Tijd = date_create();
$Tijd->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT Voorstellingsnummer FROM voorstelling v WHERE Tijd = '$Tijd' AND v.Voorstellingsnummer NOT IN(SELECT r.Voorstellingsnummer FROM reserveringen r WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50) AND Vestigingsnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdvestiging"] . "' AND Filmnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdfilmnaam"] . "';", $db);
```

The code for the 2nd try looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT Voorstellingsnummer FROM voorstelling v WHERE Tijd = '" . $_POST["Tijd"] . "' AND v.Voorstellingsnummer NOT IN(SELECT r.Voorstellingsnummer FROM reserveringen r WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50) AND Vestigingsnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdvestiging"] . "' AND Filmnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdfilmnaam"] . "';", $db);
```

The code for the 3rd try looks like this:

```
$time = $_POST["Tijd"];
$Tijd = new DateTime("$time"); 

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT Voorstellingsnummer FROM voorstelling v WHERE Tijd = '$Tijd' AND v.Voorstellingsnummer NOT IN(SELECT r.Voorstellingsnummer FROM reserveringen r WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50) AND Vestigingsnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdvestiging"] . "' AND Filmnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdfilmnaam"] . "';", $db);
```

This is the form code:

```
$resultaat = mysql_query ("SELECT Tijd FROM voorstelling v WHERE v.Voorstellingsnummer NOT IN(SELECT r.Voorstellingsnummer FROM reserveringen r WHERE r.Voorstellingsnummer = v.Voorstellingsnummer GROUP BY r.Voorstellingsnummer HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50) AND Vestigingsnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdvestiging"] . "' AND Filmnaam = '" . $_SESSION["geselecteerdfilmnaam"] . "';", $db);

$_SESSION["Tijd"] = $resultaat; //the selected Tijd records in this query are in datetime format on the server.

echo "<form action='reserveren.php' method='post'>
    <H3>Kies een Tijd</H3><br>
    <select name='Tijd'> ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($_SESSION["Tijd"])) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Tijd'] ."'>" . $row['Tijd'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>
    <input type='submit' name='Reserveer' value='Reserveren'>
    </form>";
```

Currently I'm only getting errors but what I want is for the $Tijd variable to be succesfully used inside my mysql query. SO what kind of data do I get from the select and I do I convert it to a usable datetime?

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated move onto mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: @devpro I can't. It's for a schoolproject where we are learning Mysql I'm sorry if that's a problem but because of the assignment I can't use anything other than Mysql

Comment: @devpro I'm also not sure if my teacher would want me to start adding mysqli_* into my project but if the conversion is easy which it seems it is because you just need to add 'i' after all the mysql_ I might do it and see what he thinks. But will that mess up my code? The project is due end of the coming week and I'm almost done and if the conversion makes my code a mess I'd rather not do it right now.

Comment: You can't just change `mysql` to `mysqli` unfortunately, some of the functions take different parameters.

Comment: @YvalsonDronkers, It's almost that easy, but many mysqli functions also require your connection variable as a parameter. It would be an easier conversion that switching to PDO.

Comment: The error message you are getting for the first 2 tries says that you haven't made a connection to the database. Where is your `$db = mysql_connect(...)` statement?

Comment: Well people thank you for the information about Mysqli but if I read it correctly to make that work properly it would take hours of work to convert my entire project and I currently don't have that time because of my exams I'll try to update my project in the future but for now I'm sticking with MySQL

Comment: @Nick Wow thank you that sort of fixed the error messages Now I'm only getting the error message that pops up in my 3rd try

Comment: @YvalsonDronkers that last error message is because you are trying to output an object as a string. Try adding `$Tijd = $Tijd->format('Y-m-d');` before the query (change the format to whatever is appropriate for the `Tijd` column in your table)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is sort of fixed right now because of @Nick.
Using the code from the 2nd try it stops giving me errors.
I put the query in front of my database connection which was the error.

This still didn't fix my code but now I at least know how to get further.